# Не получается отправить файл csv через бота пользователю

Tags: python, aiogram

Не получается отправить файл csv через бота пользователю

Подскажите что не так, либо покажите как правильно сразу, я уже все перепробовал, но ничего не выходит

```py
@router.message(Text(text=['/admin']))
async def admin_command_handler(message: types.Message):
    # Create a temporary CSV file to save the data
    temp_file_path = 'output_data.csv'
    with open(temp_file_path, mode='w', newline='') as csv_file:
        # Use a semicolon as the delimiter
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=';')

        # Write headers to the CSV file
        writer.writerow(['Username', 'Депозит', 'Проиграно', 'Комиссия'])

        # Assuming 'data' is a list of dictionaries with the specified keys
        for entry in data:  # Use the global 'data' variable
            writer.writerow([entry['username'], entry['purchases'], entry['netrevenue'], entry['revsharecommission']])

    # Send the CSV file to the chat by passing the file path as a string
    await message.reply_document(document=temp_file_path)

    # Optionally, you can remove the temporary file after sending it
    os.remove(temp_file_path)
```

Ошибка:

```
  File "C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiogram\client\session\base.py", line 111, in check_response
    raise TelegramBadRequest(method=method, message=description)
aiogram.exceptions.TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says Bad Request: wrong HTTP URL specified
```

Answer (score 1):

Для отправки файла, в метод `reply_document` нужно передавать экземпляр подкласса `InputFile`. В вашем случае вы хотите отправить файл просто зная путь по которому он размещен. Вот код как это сделать:

```py
from aiogram import types

@router.message(Text(text=['/admin']))
async def admin_command_handler(message: types.Message):

    ... # some code

    await message.reply_document(document=types.FSInputFile(path=temp_file_path))

    ... # some code
```